# Authorize.net Transaction Hash Upgrade for Only Authorised.net

Tags: magento-1.9, authorize.net

If Magento Store using Authorize.net method Instead of Authorize.net Direct Post then Need to install `Authorize.net Direct Post Signature Key patch`  in my magento store?

I am using `Magento version:1.9.3.3`.

Comment: you have showing in `Authorize.net Direct Post Signature Key patch` message

Comment: Yes, I have seen Message that is related to Direct Post but , what if use Authorize.net Payment method only.

Comment: you want to remove this message? and upgrade `Authorze.net`

Comment: you can check here https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024368392

Comment: My question is Magento gives two payment method Authorize.net Direct Post and Authorize.net. And Authorize.net Announced that they will stop supporting MD5. Authorize.net Direct Post Used MD5 but Authorize.net not used MD5 , So will need to Install Patch related to Authorize.net?

Comment: curently update only `Update Authorize.Net Direct Post from MD5 to SHA-512` no need to Authorize.net